# eclipse y code recommender

Tags: java, eclipse

Cuando me meto en eclipse oxygen y echo mano de code recommender la primera vez me sale el siguiente log de aviso que adjunto a a continuacion. despues de haberlo utilizado la primera vez no vuelve a pasar. Busco una solucion para arreglarlo o para hacer que este aviso en concreto no me genere un log.

EL CODIGO ES EL SIGUIENTE:

```
!SESSION 2018-01-25 12:12:31.382 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.2.M20171130-0510
java.version=1.8.0_152
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=es_ES
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.recommenders.models.rcp 1 11 2018-01-25 12:14:43.289
!MESSAGE The model index service was accessed either before it started or after it finished running.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.recommenders.utils.Logs$LogTraceException
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.utils.Logs$LogTraceException.newTrace(Logs.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.utils.Logs.log(Logs.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.utils.Logs.log(Logs.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.models.rcp.EclipseModelIndex.suggest(EclipseModelIndex.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.models.SimpleModelProvider.acquireModel(SimpleModelProvider.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.models.PoolingModelProvider.access$0(PoolingModelProvider.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.models.PoolingModelProvider$ModelPoolFactoryMediator.makeObject(PoolingModelProvider.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.models.PoolingModelProvider$ModelPoolFactoryMediator.makeObject(PoolingModelProvider.java:1)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.models.PoolingModelProvider.acquireModel(PoolingModelProvider.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.calls.rcp.RcpCallModelProvider.acquireModel(RcpCallModelProvider.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.calls.rcp.RcpCallModelProvider.acquireModel(RcpCallModelProvider.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.recommenders.internal.models.rcp.PrefetchModelArchiveJob.run(PrefetchModelArchiveJob.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo arregle si a alguien le puede ayudar los hize desactivando code reccomenders (funciona igual la ayuda sin el). Preferenced >code reccomenders> completion> deseleccionar la casilla de abajo